# service http requests in java without using a webserver

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, servlets

Can someone please let me know if we can use Restful web services or something similar to that to service HTTP requests without using a web server

Comment: By definition anything that services HTTP requests _is_ a web server...

Answer (score 0):

All the Http requests are processed or identified by the servlet or ejb component in java.

1.We must deploy restful services server side code in webserver otherwise we cannot expose our functionality over the network

2.To access the rest resource we can use normal java program or any servlet or other.

3.Without using webserver you cannot expose your rest resource over the network at serverside.